# How to correctly to dowload xlsx file on client?

Tags: javascript

I need to download a file in xlsx format. I get the contents of the file from the backend(nodeJS) and do some configuration like this :

```
  let blob = new Blob([excelData], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
```

Its just example.I use React on client. excelData looks llike [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Unz.png)

But when I try to open the downloaded file in Microsoft Excel, I get the message "the file is corrupt, it cannot be opened."
I tried to get the contents of the file through postman and open it - everything worked.

I think the problem in forming a link on the client.
Anybody can tell me how to solve this problem ?

thanks y'all

Comment: In the above, what's `excelData`?

Comment: FWIW, if you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch), you can read the response as a `Blob` directly, rather than having to create one yourself.

Comment: Try this does the job nicely I have been using it for quite some time now.. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I fixed the question. Look at the attached photo

Answer (score 0):

```
var blob = new Blob([s2ab(atob(excelData))], {      type: ''     });
 var link = document.createElement("a");
 link.download = name;
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
delete link;
function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
```

try this method if your excelData is correct then you will get the correct data format

Comment: Hi. I tried using your solution and got the following error : **Unhandled Rejection (InvalidCharacterError): Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Maybe someone will be useful. Need to get data like arrayBuffer
Example:

```
fetch('someURL').then(response => response.arrayBuffer()).then(result => {
 const blob = new Blob([result], {
          type: mimeType,
        });
})
```